# Is $\mathbb{Q}$ a subfield of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: field-theory

My book says that the rationals are a subfield of the integers, I would expect it to be the other way around: Integers being a subfield of rationals, since every element of $\mathbb{Z}$ is contained also in $\mathbb{Q}$ Why is this the case?

Comment: A subfield has to be a subset.  That is not the case here.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is the fraction field of $\mathbb{Z}$, which means that any field containing $\mathbb{Z}$ has to contain $\mathbb{Q}$. This is indeed very obvious

Answer (score 4):

The rationals are not a subfield of the integers (they aren't even a subset) and the integers are not a subfield of the rationals because the integers aren't even a field (most elements have no multiplicative inverse).

Comment: It seems that I misread it! It says that any field that contains $\mathbb{Z}$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subfield. Sorry!

Comment: @TheBosco: This is something completely different :)

Comment: That makes a lot more sense.