# Any field that contains the integers contains the rationals as a subfield (Analysis proof)

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm an intro analysis student trying to prove that any field $f$ that contains the integers contains the rationals as a subfield. I'm asked to proceed by proving  that there exists a subset $F'$ of $F$ and a function $Φ: F'→\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\mathbb{Z} ⊂ \mathbb{Q}$ and $Φ$  satisfies the three following properties:

1. $Φ $ is bijective
2. $Φ(a + b) = Φ(a) + Φ(b)$, for $a$, $b$ ∈ $F$
3. $Φ(a.b) = Φ(a).Φ(b)$, for $a$, $b ∈ F$

I have gone through a few answers for similar questions but I am not sure how to proceed. We have not covered isomorphisms in the course yet so I am unsure how this is related to it (though other posts like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237833/proof-for-any-two-ordered-fields-with-the-least-upper-bound-property-are-order-i/2237873?newreg=0fa0cbb04855481da9042ba2ef998707) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236026/is-mathbbq-a-subfield-of-mathbbz) indicate that there's a connection). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This does not belong to analysis. The question and the solution involve basis ideas from abstract algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $\mathbb{Z} \subset F$. Given $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus\{0\}$, the fact that $F$ is a field means that $nm^{-1} \in F$. How should we associate $nm^{-1}$ with a rational number?

You'll need to prove that this association is actually an isomorphism, which really just comes down to doing a few calculations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would the association just be the identity function?

Comment: Well, the element $nm^{-1} \in F$ need not actually be the *actual* rational number $n/m$. It's hard to come up with a natural example where you contain the *actual* integers but not the *actual* rationals, but imagine if you replaced every non-integer $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with something like $(x,0)$ (so just tag each non-integer with a $0$). In that case, $nm^{-1}$ would correspond to the element $(n/m,0)$. So while $nm^{-1}$ may not be the *actual* rational number $n/m$, you can still map it to $n/m$, and that will give you the relevant map.

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ is a field and $\mathbb Z \subset F$ then for any integers $m,n\ne 0$ then $m\cdot \frac 1n = \frac mn \in F$.  But $\{\frac mn|m,n\in \mathbb Z; n\ne 0\} = \mathbb Q$.  So $\mathbb Q \subset F$.

Or to look from a slightly different angle:

If $q\in \mathbb Q$ then there exist integers $m,n$ so that $q = \frac mn$ and as $m,n\in \mathbb Z\subset F$ and $F$ is a field then $\frac 1n\in F$ and $m*\frac 1n = \frac mn=q\in F$.  So $\mathbb Q \subset F$