# Any field that contains the integers contains the rationals as a subfield

Tags: real-analysis

It has pretty much been answered here, [Any field that contains the integers contains the rationals as a subfield (Analysis proof)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659754/any-field-that-contains-the-integers-contains-the-rationals-as-a-subfield-analy)

but I don't really understand how it was done. Also, is there another, simpler way to show this than the way in the question above?

Comment: If it's answered and you don't understand it, we can't restate *unless* you tell us where and why you don't understand it.

Comment: Well, actually now that I looked at the answer it could be made simpler.

Comment: @Somos The problem with that other post is that it is just a hint, not a complete proof. It is quite clear to me that the OP just struggles to fill the gaps.

Comment: I'll add an answer an the post (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659754/any-field-that-contains-the-integers-contains-the-rationals-as-a-subfield-analy/3547100#3547100) you cited and vote to close this site as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is really simple: if $F$ is a field and $m, n\in F$ are "integers", $n\ne 0$ then the numbers $\frac{m}{n}\in F$ can be viewed as "fractions"/"rational numbers". The rest is just quite a pedestrian proof to make this rigorous.

Start with formulating this problem mathematically. When a field $F$ "contains integers", it means that there is a *ring monomorphism* (1-1 homomorphism) of the ring of integers $\mathbb Z$ into $F$, e.g. $\iota:\mathbb Z\to F$. Let us extend this monomorphism to the whole $\mathbb Q$: define $i:\mathbb Q\to F$ the following way:

$$i\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)=\frac{\iota(m)}{\iota(n)}$$

Now the pedestrian bit: you need to figure out what conditions you need to prove, and then prove them... along the way using the fact that $\iota$ is a monomorphism.

- **$i$ is well-defined**. First $n\ne 0$ in $\mathbb Z$ so $\iota(n)\ne 0=\iota(0)$ in $F$ (as $\iota$ is 1-1), so the right-hand side is defined. Moreover, if you have two different fractions $\frac{m_1}{n_1}=\frac{m_2}{n_2}$, then $m_1n_2=m_2n_1$ in $\mathbb Z$, so $\iota(m_1)\iota(n_2)=\iota(m_2)\iota(n_1)$ in $F$, which implies that:

$$i\left(\frac{m_1}{n_1}\right)=\frac{\iota(m_1)}{\iota(n_1)}=\frac{\iota(m_2)}{\iota(n_2)}=i\left(\frac{m_2}{n_2}\right)$$

- **$i$ is 1-1**: very similar to the previous: if

$$i\left(\frac{m_1}{n_1}\right)=i\left(\frac{m_2}{n_2}\right)$$

then

$$\frac{\iota(m_1)}{\iota(n_1)}=\frac{\iota(m_2)}{\iota(n_2)}$$

so $\iota(m_1n_2)=\iota(m_1)\iota(n_2)=\iota(m_2)\iota(n_1)=\iota(m_2n_1)$, and now, by using the fact that $\iota$ is 1-1, you conclude that $m_1n_2=m_2n_1$, i.e. $\frac{m_1}{n_1}=\frac{m_2}{n_2}$.

- **$i$ extends our previous mapping on $\mathbb Z$**: if $n\in\mathbb Z$, then $i(n)=i\left(\frac{n}{1}\right)=\frac{\iota(n)}{\iota(1)}=\frac{\iota(n)}{1}=\iota(n)$
- **$i$ is a ring homomorphism**: need to prove simple statements such as the following:

  - $i\left(\frac{m_1}{n_1}+\frac{m_2}{n_2}\right)=i\left(\frac{m_1}{n_1}\right)+\left(\frac{m_2}{n_2}\right)$
  - $i\left(\frac{m_1}{n_1}\cdot\frac{m_2}{n_2}\right)=i\left(\frac{m_1}{n_1}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{m_2}{n_2}\right)$
  - $i\left(-\frac{m}{n}\right)=-i\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)$
  - $i(0)=0$
  - $i(1)=1$

(which I will leave to you as an exercise - the last two have already been proven in the previous step.)